# How to access the nth item in a Laravel collection?

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

I guess I am breaking all the rules by deliberately making a duplicate question...

The [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443949/how-to-access-the-nth-object-in-a-laravel-collection-object) has an accepted answer. It obviously solved the askers problem, but it did not answer the title question.

Let's start from the beginning - the `first()` method is implemented approximately like this:

```
foreach ($collection as $item)
    return $item;
```

It is obviously more robust than taking `$collection[0]` or using other suggested methods.

There might be no item with index `0` or index `15` even if there are 20 items in the collection. To illustrate the problem, let's take this collection out of the docs:

```
$collection = collect([
    ['product_id' => 'prod-100', 'name' => 'desk'],
    ['product_id' => 'prod-200', 'name' => 'chair'],
]);

$keyed = $collection->keyBy('product_id');
```

Now, do we have any reliable (and preferably concise) way to access nth item of `$keyed`?

My own suggestion would be to do:

```
$nth = $keyed->take($n)->last();
```

But this will give the wrong item (`$keyed->last()`) whenever `$n > $keyed->count()`. How can we get the nth item if it exists and `null` if it doesn't just like `first()` behaves?

### Edit

To clarify, let's consider this collection:

```
$col = collect([
    2 => 'a',
    5 => 'b',
    6 => 'c',
    7 => 'd']);
```

First item is `$col->first()`. How to get the second?

`$col->nth(3)` should return `'c'` (or `'c'` if 0-based, but that would be inconsistent with `first()`). `$col[3]` wouldn't work, it would just return an error.

`$col->nth(7)` should return `null` because there is no seventh item, there are only four of them. `$col[7]` wouldn't work, it would just return `'d'`.

You could rephrase the question as "How to get nth item in the foreach order?" if it's more clear for some.

Comment: As in the answer to the question you mentioned, you can do `$collection->get($nth, 'some default value')`

Comment: @tam It uses the keys just like `[$nth]` does...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I guess faster and more memory-efficient way is to use [`slice()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-slice) method:

```
$collection->slice($n, 1);
```

Comment: This seems nice, but I am not sure about the behaviour if `$n > $collection->count()`. It appears that `slice()` uses PHPs `array_slice()` and I can't find info on behaviour if `$n` exceeds the size of array. Maybe it's unspecified and unreliable :|

Comment: It will just return an empty collection. You even can do easy check with `->isEmpty()` or `empty($result)`.

Comment: Mkay, then `$collection->slice($n, 1)->fiirst()` will return nth item if it exists and `null` otherwise. Seems great :)

Comment: Two issues with this answer to consider: a) this returns a collection of one, so `$collection->slice($n, 1)->first()` must be used; b) `$n` is zero indexed, so will return the `$n+1` element from the collection. So for this example use: `$collection->slice($n-1, 1)->first()`

Answer (score 11):

You can try it using [`values()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-values) function as:

```
$collection->values()->get($n);
```

Comment: This seems the best solution so far, can't think of an example where it fails :)

Comment: It's working solution but it will duplicate whole collection and may kill an app, if collection is big by itself (collection of articles with relations or something similar).

Answer (score 9):

Based on Alexey's answer, you can create a macro in AppServiceProvider (add it inside register method):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

Collection::macro('getNth', function ($n) {
   return $this->slice($n, 1)->first();
});
```

and then, you can use this throughout your application:

```
$collection = ['apple', 'orange'];

$collection->getNth(0) // returns 'apple'
$collection->getNth(1) // returns 'orange'
$collection->getNth(2) // returns null
$collection->getNth(3) // returns null
```

Answer (score 8):

you may use `offsetGet` since `Collection` class implements `ArrayAccess`

```php
$lines->offsetGet($nth);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best option, but, you can get item from array inside collection

```
$collection->all()[0]
```